# Effort in-memory database with shared connection

Tags: c#, .net, in-memory-database, effort

I'm currently working with effort to make some tests with in-memory database (with this library: https://entityframework-effort.net/).

The issue I'm having is that I get an exception when trying to use a shared connection for all my contexts.

Here's what I'm working with :

```
var connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
referenceDbContext = new ReferenceDbContext(connection);
personDbContext = new PersonDbContext(connection);
referenceDbContext.AddRange(...); // this works fine
referenceDbContext.SaveChanges(); // same context works fine too
personDbContext.AddRange(...); // other context: this fails
...
```

The stacktrace :

```
Message: 
    System.InvalidOperationException : Index was not found
  Stack Trace: 
    DatabaseReflectionHelper.FindIndex(ITable table, IKeyInfo key, Boolean unique)
    DatabaseReflectionHelper.CreateAssociation(Database database, DbRelationInfo relation)
    DbContainer.Initialize(DbSchema schema)
    DbContainer.Initialize(StoreItemCollection edmStoreSchema)
    <>c__DisplayClass7_0.<DbCreateDatabase>b__0(DbConnection x)
    EffortProviderServices.Wrap[T](DbConnection connection, Func`2 action)
    EffortProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
    DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
    ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
    DatabaseOperations.Create(ObjectContext objectContext)
    DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
    InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
    Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
    CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    <>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0()
    InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
    InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
    <>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c)
    RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
    LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
    LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
    InternalContext.Initialize()
    InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
    InternalSet`1.Initialize()
    InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
    InternalSet`1.AddRange(IEnumerable entities)
    DbSet`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 entities)
```

Anyone having an idea why ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why? Seems like an anti pattern to me. Let the connection pool do its job, and create and dispose connections.

Comment: I'm doing functional unit tests and instead of mocking every single piece of code I'm actually going the the concrete implementation to be more "real" to what's actually happening. That means that my database related operations have to be made in memory thanks to effort which should handle the connection by itself. The CreatePersistent method snippet says the following : Creates a EffortConnection object that rely on an in-memory database instance that lives during the complete application lifecycle.

Comment: After further investigation I found that this is due to some context that have views in them. But what is weird is that somehow the exception is not raised when I create a new connection for those context.